# BSOD nvlddmkm.sys VIDEO TDR Failure on win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

MSI GT70

cause blue screen on every application that use nvidia graphic:

[image]

steps that I have done:

- upgrade graphic driver:(work utill close 3d app and reopen it);
- increase TDR delay on Registery(work 1 hour and then bsod);
- uninstall and reinstall Driver in safe mode(work only 3 hour and then bsod);

Comment: Information on the BSOD is required to help

Comment: VIDOE_TDR_Failure (nvlddmkm.sys)

Comment: Yeah; Not enough information. BlueScreenViewer will tell you every driver that was opened when the BSOD happend. We need more information.  The problem is connect to your Nvidia drivers.  If your using the current version, and this happens, then the problem are the drivers.

Comment: here is my BLue Screen Error

Comment: here is my BLue Screen Error 
http://s30.postimg.org/5yqtbvojl/Untitled.jpg

Comment: I Installed Windows 7 And Same Issue :(